# Need to import and use the digital certificate dynamically in java

Tags: java, security

I'm writing a web service client in java using JAX-RPC This service provider is using SSL for authentication. And I'm completely new to this SSL/HTTPS implementation.
So my requirement is to import their digital certificate and use it for sending the request. But I don't want to create ant trustStore or keystore in my local and import it from there. All I want is to complete all the above task dynamically without making any changes in my current cacert file or without creating any new one. Hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Finally I got the answer, Just need to import the certificate at run time and inject it while sending the request. It works for me.
Code snippet is as follws---

Comment: well, you are not really using any certificate for sending, you are just accepting any certificate presented by the server at face value.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Finally I got the answer, Just need to import the certificate at run time and inject it while sending the request. It works for me.
    Code snippet is as follows:

    private HttpURLConnection getHTTPConnection(){
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }


                public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }


                public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    System.out.println("authType is " + authType);
                    System.out.println("cert issuers");
                    for (int i = 0; i < certs.length; i++) {
                        System.out.println("\t" + certs[i].getIssuerX500Principal().getName());
                        System.out.println("\t" + certs[i].getIssuerDN().getName());
                    }
                }
            } };
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
                HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
                URL myurl = new URL("END_POINT");
                connection = (HttpURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
                connection.setFollowRedirects(true);
                connection.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
            } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
                mue.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }
return connection;
              }
```